# What does the term "nested region" mean in image processing?

Tags: image, image-processing

I am reading a technical paper in digital image processing and they used the term "nested region". Could anybody kindly explain what does it mean?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context it it difficult to say. But generally it means that some region inside other region is processed.